# Get the last day of the last month and the first day of next month in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

If i have for example :

> '2020-01-01'

I want to have two dates :

-The last day of the prévious month :

> '2019-12-31'

-The first day of next month :

> '2020-02-01'

I tried to use something like `echo date("Y-n-31", strtotime('2020-01-01'));` but i don't know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php

$month_end = new DateTime("last day of last month");
$month_ini = new DateTime("first day of next month");

echo $month_end->format('Y-m-d'); // will print, Last day of last month
echo $month_ini->format('Y-m-d'); // will print First day of next month

?>
```

> With Datetime object with user defined date (Custom date)

```
# with datetime object
$d1 = new DateTime('2019-12-01');
$d1 -> modify('last day of last month');
echo $d1 -> format('d.m.Y'), "\n";

$d2 = new DateTime('2019-12-01');
$d2 -> modify('first day of next month');
echo $d2 -> format('d.m.Y'), "\n";

Output:
30.11.2019
01.01.2020
```

Comment: This is nice but how would you do it with respect to a particular date?

Comment: @vivek_23  Can be used with `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month', strtotime('2019-12-01')));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month', strtotime('2019-12-01')));` in this example: **2019-12-01 is my current month.**

Comment: I know that. I was more curious to know with datetime.

Comment: We can have some luck with DateInterval class.

Comment: @vivek_23 Answer updated with Datetime & CUSTOM DATE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213095/2568750

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Use strtotime() for add month or minus month

```
$date='2020-01-01';
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime('-1 month'.$date)); //2019-12-31
echo date("Y-m-01", strtotime('+1 month'.$date)); //2020-02-01
```

Comment: Nice to use the `t` format character for date formatting. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Anyone know how to use this with DateTime object ?

Answer (score 1):

**strtotime()**
this php function convert english textual date-time discription into UNIX timestamp

- the first step converts textual date-time into a timestamp
- now you have timestamp then use the date() function

*-The last day of the prévious month :*

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Last day of last month"));
```

*-The first day of next month :*

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("First day of next month"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime's method `modify()` to achieve relative dates:

```
<?php

$dateOld = new \DateTimeImmutable('2020-01-01');

echo $dateOld->modify("last day of last month")->format('Y-m-d');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $dateOld->modify("first day of next month")->format('Y-m-d');
```

Try it here: https://3v4l.org/qALa5

Answer (score 0):

```
$date='2020-01-01';
echo date("Y-m-d", 'last day of previous month', strtotime($date)));
echo date("Y-m-d", 'first day of next month', strtotime($date)));
```